# Does it make sense to have a function of class $k + 1$ defined on a surface of class $C^k$?

Tags: analysis, manifolds, surfaces

I have my doubt about the next definition:

Let $M\subset R^n$ be a surface m-dimensional of class $C^k$. We say a function $f:M\longrightarrow R^l$ is class $C^r$ with $0<r<k+1$, if $f ( \phi )$ is class $C^r$, with $\phi :V_0\longrightarrow V$ parameterization $C^k$.

For surface I understand the next:

A surface m-dimensional and class $C^k$ on $R^n$, is a set $M\subset R^n$ such that for every $p\in M$ there exist a open set $U_\alpha \subset R^n$ such that $p\in U_\alpha \cap M=V_\alpha $, and a parameterization m-dimensional and class $C^k$,  $\phi _\alpha: V_0\longrightarrow V_\alpha $.

My question is: why must $r$ be less than $k+1$?...has sense if $r>k$?...for instance, May I have a function $f$ on a surface $C^k$, being $f$ class $C^{k+1}$?

Comment: Makes no sense. Your function may be $C^{k+1}$ in some chart, but as soon as you change charts, you will be down to $C^k$, since the transition functions are only that regular.

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance but I still don't know what a transition function is...

Comment: If $\phi_\alpha$ and $\phi_\beta$ are two of your parameterizations, the following is called a transition function: $\phi_\alpha\circ\phi_\beta^{-1}$. It is defined on a suitable smaller domain than $V_\beta$. Hopefully I will write a more detailed answer later if I find some time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To define the regularity of a function $f\colon M\to \mathbb R$ you need to compose it with a parameterization, so you define
$$
f_\alpha:=f\circ \phi_\alpha\colon V_0\to \mathbb R.$$
Here I am adopting your notation, and in particular, I remark that $V_0$ is an open set in $\mathbb R^m$ (you did not state this precisely - please pay attention to this, it is very important).

We say that $f\in C^\ell(M)$ if and only if $M$ is covered by coordinate patches $V_{\alpha_1}, V_{\alpha_2},\ldots$ in such a way that $f_{\alpha_j}\in C^\ell(V_0)$. Notice that, since $V_0$ is an open set in Euclidean space, $C^\ell(V_0)$ is defined in terms of partial derivatives, as is standard in calculus.

It is desirable that this definition automatically implies that all $f_\beta$ are $C^\ell$, regardless of whether $\beta$ is one of the $\alpha_j$ or not. Now, for all $\alpha$ and $\beta$, we have the change of parameterization formula
$$
f_\beta=f_\alpha\circ(\phi_\alpha^{-1}\circ\phi_\beta).$$
Note that this function is defined on the open set $\phi^{-1}(V_\alpha\cap V_\beta)$, provided this is not empty.

We notice that the *transition function* $\phi_\alpha^{-1}\circ\phi_\beta$ needs not be more regular than $C^k$, where $k$ is the regularity of the manifold $M$. Therefore, even if $f_\alpha$ is smoother than $C^k$, after composing with the transition function it might lose some regularity, and we can only guarantee that $f_\beta$ is $C^k$.

We conclude that the highest possible level of regularity that a function $f\colon M\to \mathbb R$ can achieve is $k$.

Comment: ooh I've noticed that my ideas was disordering. You've order my mind. Now I understand that class of a function over a manifold is completely determinate to the charts.  Thank's a lot for dedicate me your time. However...I ask me if may there exist a case when all $f_\beta $ may be somoother than $C^k$ same that $f_\alpha $

Comment: Yes, there is for example the trivial case of $f=0$ at all points of $M$. For this function, every $f_\alpha$ is also equal to $0$ identically, so it is as regular as possible.

Comment: You are right!... Thanks a lot!... You helped me too much!

Comment: No problem, glad it helped. If you think that this answer was useful do not forget to accept it, please.